# How to return several rows as arrays instead of one long column postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have an SQL statement that looks like this:

```
select id
from some_table
limit 100
```

It obviously is going to provide a single column result set with an id for each row.

The result set I am trying to get would take the 100 `ids` and break them into 4 separate rows with an array of 25 `ids`. Something like:

```
COL     ARRAY
1       23,1231,123,41,1,1,231,2312
2       12,12,31,23,1,23,1,23,12,31
3       123,1,123,1,2,12,123123,123
4       2,123,1,2,12,31,2,23,12,312
```

This then does bring the result of the 100 `ids` I requested, but gives them to me in batches.

I am scratching my head on how to get this using straight sql (of course I can do this with PHP and might just have to).

Seems like there must be some sort of window function I could implement for it using straight SQL.

I am using Postgres version 9.4.1

Thank you.

Comment: Something like `with t(x,y) as (select id, (row_number() over() - 1) / 25 from some_table limit 100) select y, array_agg(x) from t group by y;`

Comment: Brilliant - worked perfectly! Who would have thought simple division could handle that...